# How to modify layers of static swf file (image) and create its preview in php

Tags: php, flash

I would like to know, how to work with SWF images in PHP. My SWF image has some layers and I need to modify their opacity and colors if it is possible.
I also need to generate some type (jpg,png,...) of image preview.

I found something about Ming library, but I read It is not possible to create image preview using it and I can not understand how to modify my swf file.

Answer (score 0):

SWF isn't an image file, it is a published Flash file that isn't editable. Even if you import it into Adobe Flash you still won't have access to all of the assets it contains.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF

Comment: Ok, in fact, I do not exactly understand how SWF files works. I have some SWF files which contain vector graphics I think. But I don't need to modify SWF file itself. I have to only create some preview of SWF file somehow.

Comment: I would like to do something like this: user can upload vector graphics image with some layers. After uploading user can manage some colors and other properties of defined layers. That is how user can generate previews in different colors of the same image. Could you recommend me some file format ? I have though it is possible using SWF files because one of my friends can do It in Java or Flash in browser. I do not know how It works. Thanks.